# Missing directive or assembly on build time

Tags: c#

I am building a solution that refers to several projects.
I'm adding the references to them with several usings, and VS does not mark any problem during the writing, but when I build I get this error:

```
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'OrderRules' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is one of the classes were the error is happening:

```
using OrderRules.Interface;

namespace OrderRule.Quantity
{
    public class MaxStarshipRule : OrderRules.Interface.IOrderRule
    {
        public OrderRules.Interface.OrderRuleResult CheckRule(OrderTaker.SharedObjects.Order order)
        {
            var passed = true;
            var message = string.Empty;

            foreach (var item in order.OrderItems)
            {
                if (item.ProductItem.ProductName == "Starship" && item.Quantity > 1)
                {
                    passed = false;
                    message = "Maximum of 1 starship per order";
                }
            }
            return new OrderRuleResult(passed, message);
        }

        public string RuleName
        {
            get { return "Maximum Starship Rule"; }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks normal to me, can you see anything?

Comment: Restart your IDE and you'll get incorrect code fragments underlined.

Comment: I did it, but they are not underlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

- you added all the required project references
- you added all the required `using XXX`
- Visual Studio allows you to write your type/namespace without telling you it doesn't exist (syntax highlighting is OK)
- it fails only once you compile your projects

then check all your projects are targeting the same platform (or at least targeted platforms are compatibles). For example, don't reference an assembly targeting .Net 4.0 (full) from an assembly targeting .Net 4.0 (client profile).

Comment: One of the projects was targeting .Net 4.0, while all the others were targeting 4.5.